# Why does my file keep opening in read-only mode? Usual suspects have been ruled out

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a fairly large and complex excel spreadsheet that I've built, and I'm the original author. It's currently being saved on a network drive.

Me and one other person both use and edit this spreadsheet. However, if I'm the last person to have made changes, and he opens the spreadsheet, it opens in read-only mode, and he has to save-as to get it saved.

Same in reverse for me - if he's saved off a new version to get his edits in, I now open in read-only, and need to save off into a new version.

No error messages are generated, or alerts created, when doing this. I open the file, it seems to open normally, and ends up opening in read-only mode.

Things I've looked into:

1) No permissions are set in the file to force opening in read-only mode.
2) The file is closed everywhere else before opening it. There is no "File is already in use" message.
3) Both of us are able to save to the same network drive, so it seems unlikely that network permissions are involved.
4) We're opening it directly from the network drive, we're not sending it over e-mail to each other.

This is somewhat inconvenient (but livable), but not knowing the why is driving me nuts. Does anyone else know a reason why the files would constantly be opening in read-only mode?

Comment: Are you using Office 365 ?

Comment: Yes. Office 365, Windows 10 OS

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem saving to a local drive? Have you verified on the server where the file is stored that there are in fact no locks on the file after the first person closes it? Does this happen if the first person gets in but closes *without* saving changes?

Comment: Are you using [co-authoring](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/collaborate-on-excel-workbooks-at-the-same-time-with-co-authoring-7152aa8b-b791-414c-a3bb-3024e46fb104) and would you consider it as a better solution?

Comment: No co-authoring being used. Saving to the local drive probably wouldn't help, since it'd be the same "person" accessing the file (due to the setup of the network). Verified no locks. Haven't checked if entered but leaves without saving - that is on my "to check" list

Comment: Does  " cr8 new file > paste exactly the same content > save as different file name + folder " will reproduce the same error (read-only)? if no.. then re-cr8-ting the file is my suggested solution.

Comment: Recreating the entire file, with the amount of power query involved, isn't a really practical troubleshooting step - there were 51 queries involved at last count